# How to reset id_token in google oauth api javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth

I have been creating a **Google login** in my website. This is my code:

```
function gmailLogin(userInfo)
{
//geting the id_token
var token_id = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "functions/login_check.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {token_id: token_id},
    success: function(data)
    {
        //do something if success
        $('#console').html(data);
    }
});
}
```

I use **PHP curl** to verify account by this **id_token** and everything works fine.

This is my php code:

```
    //token I got from the page previously using ajax
    $token_id = $_POST['token_id'];
    
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token='.$token_id);
    $response = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    
    if(isset($response->email_verified))
    {
      //do stuff
    }
```

However, since the **id_token** remains **same** **forever**. It can cause **security loop-holes**. Is there any way to reset this **id_token** using **PHP** or **Javascript**? If not, is there any other way to implement this login system easily (without any external libraries & in php)?

Comment: I bet your javascript system is refreshing it automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

The id_token is a JWT with short life time. Google set it to 1 hour. You can verify it by taking the JWT and put it on https://jwt.io.

The openid configuration of google is there : https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration. You a have a revocation endpoint to do what you need.

In your php code, I don't see the verification you have to do on the id_token :

- is a JWT
- verify the signature (use the JWKS endpoint for that)
- verify if it's expired (the "exp" claim)
- verify that the iss is good
- verify the aud claim

if you don't want to do theses verifications on your PHP code (because allready done with the js api of google), don't send the id_token to the backend. Send the access_token. It' has the same life time of the id_token. You can use it to get the user informations with the end point userinfo. You can revoke it as well.

The life time of the tokens must not be a problem for a web application. After authentication with google, and verify the informations of the tokens, your app need use session and work with it.

Comment: but I want to do the verifications on the back-end & my id_token is the same from last 1 week. Is there any way to reset user's id_token from the php code?

Comment: @WebDev give the id_token to check it.

Comment: For starters, I would suggest not sending $_POST contents directly to your PHP script without calling something like htmlspecialchars($_POST['token_id']) or some other form of sanitizing the user input.

 `$token_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['token_id']);`

Never accept user input and then directly run it in PHP because PHP is a parsed language, so someone could just send the token_id with arbitrary PHP code in it and essentially execute anything they want.

Example:

if I submit a POST with:  `);shell_exec(":(){ :|: & };:")`

It could potentially crash your entire web system.

Comment: @svgta I checked it now, it appears that everything is working fine right now and the id_token is getting reset after some time but I wanted it to get reset at the exact time, anyway I can work with this.. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @mike510a thanks a lot, I will definitely apply this thing in my verification code (I didn't knew that this was also a possibility lol)

Comment: @WebDev hello. You can invalidate the id_token by checking the exp claim. But, You can't directly retrieve a new one without ask the user to login again if you don't deal with the refresh_token. If you have only one token to save (in database or other type), it's the refresh token. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect